# Trying to install Java8 on Linux Mint and set to default

Tags: java, linux-mint

I'm fairly new to using **Linux Mint** and the software I'm trying to install requires some tweaks apparently and is not supported by the company but they do provide a `.sh` file. Below are the instructions from the website.

> thinkorswim requires Java 1.8.0_60 JRE to run. A typical method for
>   some Linux variants To install java 8 on the machine is:
>
> ```
> sudo apt-add-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
> sudo apt-get update
> sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer
> ```
>
> Your specific process may differ, please consult the distribution
>   maintainer for instructions on your varient. To install thinkorswim:
>
> ```
> Click "Install thinkorswim" to download the thinkorswim installer to a directory on your PC.
> After downloading open a shell and CD to the directory where you downloaded the installer.
> At the prompt type: sh ./thinkorswim_installer.sh
> ```
>
> Note: Clients intending to run thinkorswim on Linux, Solaris or other
>   Unix variants, manual updates and tuning may be required, we have no
>   official support for configuring these operating systems.

When I run the first command it basically tells me to check out this website to install Java8 http://www.webupd8.org/2014/03/how-to-install-oracle-java-8-in-debian.html

When I go to run `apt-get install oracle-java8-installer` I receive the following message.

> Reading package lists... Done Building dependency tree        Reading
>   state information... Done Package oracle-java8-installer is not
>   available, but is referred to by another package. This may mean that
>   the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or is only available from
>   another source
>
> E: Package 'oracle-java8-installer' has no installation candidate

I also tried `sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-set-default` as the website suggests using this package to set Java8 as default which I believe would be required to run the software I'm trying to install. Unfortunately, I receive the following error.

> E: Unable to locate package oracle-java8-set-default

Any suggestions on this matter would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: That PPA no longer works.

Comment: Any idea how to install in manually?

Comment: Maybe someone else but not me. All I know is that instructions are very outdated, the PPA doesn't  work since more than a year  ago,  and the Java version  you want is also unsupported.